# Как привязать к таймеру собственную процедуру, в PascalABC.NET?

Tags: pascalabc.net, таймер

Как привязать к таймеру собственную процедуру, в PascalABC.NET если используется
System Windows Forms ?

Помогите пожалуйста на любом примере.

Не понимаю как привязать к тику таймера процедуру.
Буду благодарен любым примерам.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная справка PABC .NET

```
uses Timers;

procedure TimerProc;
begin
  write(1);
end;


begin
  var t := new Timer(100,TimerProc);
  t.Start;
  Sleep(3000);
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, но этот способ не работает если используется system.windows.forms . Мне удалось создать и запустить таймер с помощью var t1:= new system.Windows.Forms.Timer; Но как привязать к нему процедуру - не понимаю.